# Working with parameters in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an (either or) situation in regards to parameters in SSRS 2008. I currently have my report working with a date range but I've been asked to add a drop down for the user to select the weekending date. I've got that drop down working but how can I switch between parameters (Date Range and the use of the Weekending Date drop down) for sending parameters to my report?

Comment: Do your date parameters have dropdown date lists, or are they freeform entry or specialised date pickers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I allways fix this is by setting the parameters as nullable.
Then in my sql script I select all dates on the weekending date or between the daterange:
So whatever the user specifies, your sql script is filtered based on their parameters.

```
select *
from [table] t
   where t.[date] = @WeekendingDate 
      or t.[date] is between @DateRangeFrom and @DateRangeTo
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this situation by creating an Internal Parameter(s) to sit between the UI and the query or stored procedure. The Internal Parameters are driven by expression depending on the user selection.

so lets say you want the user to either select a  begin and end date range(Begin: 2012-01-01 End: 2012-01-31), or a month (Jan 2012).

If they select a value for Month. I convert that to an equivalent date range in the internal parameter expression. If they enter a date range I just pass through the begin and end values to the internal parameters.

Hopefully this makes sense. with a little work and imagination I think the approach can handle most scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility would be to use the version control system of your choice to make another branch for the second report, change that one to use Week Ending, and then just make sure you merge changes every time you make a change to the main report.

I'm sure someone will come up with a cleaner way to handle it, though...

Comment: Um this answer.... is umm.. I don't know if I can automate that, and I don't exactly know what your talking about, is this something you have done before? This is just a simple report in SSRS...

Comment: I haven't done it before, because I've been working in Crystal, which doesn't allow merging changes into a binary file. This is one of the primary reasons I'm trying to move my development toward SSRS, though. 

There's some explanation of how to do this with Subversion, for example, at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html.

Comment: Sounds to me like the OP wants *the user* to choose between either using a date range, or selecting a value from the dropdown. Not two different reports, I think.

Comment: You are right Arjan but now I'll never get a definitive answer because this guy has confused everyone who reads the thread

Comment: Well, @Lyle, it was not totally clear to me either, and it is the responsibility of the question asker to be as clear as possible. Note the "edit" link underneath your question: besides responding to comments, it's much better to also edit your question to clarify things for everybody! Success!